# Plotting a geom_arc() over a geom_point() plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to plot a 90 degree arc from the x axis to the y axis as part of a geom_point() plot I already have with the aim of creating two parts to the graph, inside the arc and outside.

This is the data I have:

```
set.seed(1)
vector1 <- sample(1:500,250, replace = T)
vector2 <- replicate(250,min(sample(200,2,replace=TRUE)))

so.df <- data.frame(vector1, vector2)
so.df

ggplot(data = so.df, aes(x=vector2, y=vector1)) + geom_point()
```

I would like the arc to go from 100 on the y-axis to 100 on the x-axis with a radius of 10.

If I can clarify anything further please ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the necessary coordinates using a little bit of geometry and then add it on in an additional `geom_line`:

```
set.seed(1)
vector1 <- sample(1:500,250, replace = T)
vector2 <- replicate(250,min(sample(200,2,replace=TRUE)))

so.df <- data.frame(vector1, vector2)
so.df

arc_data <- data.frame(
  x = 0:100
) %>%
  mutate(y = sqrt(100^2 - x^2))

ggplot(data = so.df, aes(x=vector2, y=vector1)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y), data = arc_data, col = "red")
```

[image]

That being said, I'm not sure how something with radius 10 reaches 100 on both axes?

Comment: Thank you, I think I was getting myself in a muddle last night with what I wanted to achieve. I really want to plot a modules arc with radius 10, but that doesn’t necessarily mean going through 100 on both Aries, please could you help me with this?

Comment: what exactly is a modules arc?